# Can SSIS Packages copy large amount of data between servers

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-replication

I am confused as to what problems ssis packages solve. I need to create an application to copy content from our local network to our live servers across a dedicated line, that may be unreliable. From our live server the content needs to be replicated across all other servers. The database also needs to be updated with all the files that arrived successfully so it may be available to the user.

I was told that ssis can do this but my question is, is this the right thing to us? SSIS is for data transformation, not for copying files from one network to the other. Can ssis really do this?

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb is: if no transformation, no aggregation, no data mapping and no disparate sources then no SSIS.

You may want to explore Transactional Replication:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx

and if you are on SQL Server 2012 you can also take a look at Availability Groups: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877884.aspx

Comment: How does ssis deploy do I need a sql server?

Answer (score 0):

I would use SSIS for this scenario.  It has built in restart functionality ("checkpoints") which I would use to manage partial retries when your line fails.  It is also easy to configure the Control Flow so tasks can run in parallel, e.g. Site 2 isn't left waiting for data if Site 1 is slow.